# Enforce NULL checking in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

My method can return some kind of pointer ( for example boost::shared_ptr ) and this pointer may be NULL. Is there is any way to enforce users of my code to check, if it is empty or not ?

Some example of such things - scals's Option container, may be boost has something like boost::option ?

Comment: why do you want the users to check instead of you checking the post condition before returning your shared_ptr?

Comment: You cannot force checking the return type for `NULL`. The most some compilers offer is warning on unused function result. Might an exception be more appropriate?

Comment: "enforce users of my code to check" — and do what if the check fails?

Comment: Would love to see a C/C++ linter that can opt into enforcing NULL checks. A FOSS one, besides PC Lint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

- return a smart pointer type that throws an exception if accessed and set to NULL.
- throw an exception instead of returning a NULL pointer
- return a std::optional (or boost::optional) which expresses intent (i.e. "value may be missing") much better than a pointer

Comment: And the first two solutions don't really address the issue.  Presumably, there are cases when the function should return a null pointer; the client must test, and behave differently in such cases.  It's possible to do this with an exception, but makes things particularly unwieldly if the check should occur immediately in the calling function.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is to wrap the return value in a class, which
contains a flag which is set if the pointer is checked or
copied, and whose destructor crashes if the flag wasn't set.
Something like:

```
template <typename T>
class MustBeChecked
{
    T* myValue;
    mutable bool myHasBeenChecked;
public:
    MustBeChecked( T* value )
        : myValue( value )
        , myHasBeenChecked( false )
    {
    }
    MustBeChecked( MustBeChecked const& other )
        : myValue( other.myValue )
        , myHasBeenChecked( false )
    {
        other.myHasBeenChecked = true;
    }
    ~MustBeChecked()
    {
        assert( myHasBeenChecked );
    }

    bool operator==( nullptr_t ) const
    {
        myHasBeenChecked = true;
        return myValue == nullptr;
    }

    bool operator!=( nullptr_t ) const
    {
        myHasBeenChecked = true;
        return myValue != nullptr;
    }

    operator T*() const
    {
        assert( myHasBeenChecked );
        return myValue;
    }
};
```

To be frank, I find this to be overkill in most cases.  But I've
seen it used on some critical systems.

Answer (score 1):

The reality here is that the callers of your function already have to check. If they try to access the shared pointer without checking, then a seg-fault is coming their way if the underlying pointer is NULL.

You don't specify if you're writing a library, or some code within a project. Nor do you specify any details of the context this code lives in -- all of these might decide which approach I'd take in this situation -- but broadly speaking, all of utnapistim's suggestions are good ones.